# Laravel Echo.join is throwing Error in pusher

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

I am using presence channel to broadcast event. Echo.join is working but the listen part is not working. The Error log in pusher shows the below error message:

> Cannot broadcast client event (connection not subscribed to channel presence-chat)

Same setup for private and public events  is working fine. I clear cache and restart server just in case it might be the reason but still not working.

Broadcast Channel route is

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    return ['id' => $user->id, 'name' => $user->name];
});
```

i tried hard coded values too.

client  side code:

```
Echo.join(`chat`)
           .here()
           .joining()
           .leaving()
           .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {

               console.log( e );
               this.chat.message.push( e.msg );
               this.chat.user.push( e.user );
               this.chat.color.push( 'warning' );
               this.chat.time.push( this.getTime() );


           });



/* ChatEvent in laravel : */

    public function broadcastOn()
    {

        return new PresenceChannel('chat');
    }
```